# How to handle popover in Swift when the device orientation is changing on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I'm creating a popover using `popoverPresentationController` in Swift. It displays fine for the first time but when I rotate the device it changes its source position.
How can I make it stick at its original source point irrespective of the orientation?

The code that i did.

@IBAction func btn_popover_click(sender: UIButton) {

```
    let menuViewController = PopoverViewController()
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 100) // Size of popover.

    popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender.superview
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
    presentViewController(
        menuViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Make sure the view controller presenting the popover conforms to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate.

Example:

```
class MyViewContoller: UIVIewContoller, UIPUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate 
{

// your code...

// MARK: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate Methods

func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>) {
    let viewFrame = popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.view.frame
    let deltaX = viewFrame.height - rect.pointee.midX
    rect.pointee = CGRect(x: viewFrame.width - deltaX, y: rect.pointee.maxY, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should consider about `AutoLayout`, which is efficient way handle the object's(like `Label`, `Button`,etc) position and size on the different size screens and rotation screens. AutoLayout can be set in the storyboard or as the part of your code.

By the way, the `AutoLayout` is so much that it is hard to say. I recommend you see this [Tutorial about the AutoLayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1).

Comment: Auto layout is already set for the button from which I'm presenting the popover. The button is at its place. But the popover gets misplaced.

Comment: I've edited the question above and the code is there. The button is present in the centre of screen irrespective of the orientation.

Comment: Right, the `AutoLayout` can also handle the layout stuff for the Rotation Screen. I think the reason why your objects gone when your rotated the screen is all the things are still layout in Portrait Mode. You need to `Redraw` the `view`. Try this, in your `storyboard`, turn to the `Inspector Attribute` Menu when you select the `ViewController`, change the `Mode` from `Scale to Fill` to `redraw`.

Comment: No success yet. I think the issue is I provided sourceRect as the button's frame in current orientation. So now when the view gets rotated the button changes its position according to the layout but the view is stuck to the initial frame of the button.

Comment: Yep, you can set button's frame only with the size, nor the position. And why don't you set the size and position with the AutoLayout in the storyboard?

Comment: I have done the same. There is only one button in my view and I have added Horizontal center and vertical center in container. That's nowhere a problem. But how should I add constraints for popover?

Comment: Sorry, for honestly, I never used the `popover ViewController`, the new feature from iOS 8, in my project. You said a button showed , which means `AutoLayout` can handle the layout stuff for rotation screen. I recommend you modify the `AutoLayout` constrains setting for more times.

Comment: Thanks for your effort by the way. I'll try finding the proper solution over the net.